# MySQL inner join with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-delete

Let's say I have the following table called `Email`, where `Id` is the primary key:

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | anne@example.com |
| 2  | cat@example.com  |
| 3  | anne@example.com |
+----+------------------+
```

I'm trying to delete all occurrences of duplicates except the first. So in this case the desired output would be

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | anne@example.com |
| 2  | cat@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

After asking a friend, I found this solution works:

```
DELETE t1 FROM Person t1 INNER JOIN Person t2
Where t1.Email=t2.Email and t1.Id > t2.Id
```

My question is why does this work? In particular, when `t1` inner joins `t2` on `Email` field, how does the program know which row of `anne@example.com` should be matched with which, since there are multiple occurrences of this value with different Ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this select statement only filtering by equality among email columns

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
  FROM Person t1 
 INNER JOIN Person t2
 WHERE t1.Email=t2.Email 
 ORDER BY t1.Id, t2.Id;
```

returns `(1,1), (1,3), (3,1), (3,3)` for t1.id and t2.id values respectively for the mail `anne@example.com`, and only `(2,2)` for `cat@example.com`. Then If you consider the other filter `AND t1.Id > t2.Id`,

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
  FROM Person t1 
 INNER JOIN Person t2
 WHERE t1.Email=t2.Email 
   AND t1.id > t2.id
 ORDER BY t1.Id, t2.Id;
```

then you'll only have one tuple `(3,1)` since `t1.id > t2.id` is satisfied only for this case of id tuples. If you convert `SELECT t1.*, t2.*` to `DELETE t1` (of course remove `ORDER BY` part also), then obviously you'll delete `id = 3` and left rows with id values `1` and `2`, reversely if you replace `SELECT t1.*, t2.*` with `DELETE t2`, then you'll have rows with id values `2` and `3`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=56a41d282f0fad7c7e08f44f67699525)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I'd add that `DELETE t1` deletes rows present in the t1 table that fulfill the query criteria. (Was initially confused whether `DELETE t1` deleted columns or rows, until I looked at the syntax for Multi-table delete at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, this is more commonly written using aggregation:

```
DELETE p
    FROM Person p INNER JOIN
         (SELECT p2.email, MIN(p2.id) as min_id
          FROM Person p2
          GROUP BY p2.email
         ) p2
         ON p.email = p2.email and p.id > p2.min_id;
```

Why does your version work?  Well, it works because of the fact that a `join` not only matches data but also filters data.

So, the condition

```
t1.Email = t2.Email and t1.Id > t2.Id
```

Says that for each record in `t1` find matching records in t2 where `t1.id > t2.id`.  That is, find records in `t1` that have a matching record with a *smaller* `id`.

All records have this property -- except for one for each email.  That would be the record with the smallest id.

I do not recommend this method for identifying the smallest record, because the `join` multiplies the number of records.  If one email has five records, then there are up to four matches for one of the records.  MySQL needs to figure out what to do when you say to delete a single record four times.  (It does the right thing, of course, but there is extra work.)

The aggregation method doesn't have any issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You compare two identical tables and check all occurrences where emailaddress of both tables are identical.

if the id is the same, the row is ignored.

If the **id is different** and it must have an id **that is bigger than the id of first occurrence** , this row gets deleted.